# Python 2.7.8 for line iteration error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to iterate over all lines in a file with the following script

```
import sys

infile = open("test.txt")
infile.read()

for line in infile
    if line.find("This") != -1
        print line

infile.close()
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this error message:

```
  File "getRes.py", line 6
    for line in infile
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've been trying for an hour to figure out what is the error and I am still not able to find it. Can you tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?

PS: I am using Python 2.7.8, I would like to use this old version instead of a more recent version.

Comment: That means you're missing a colon after infile, it should be `for line in infile:`

Answer (score 2):

You need a colon after any line that introduces a block in Python.

```
for line in infile:
    if line.find("This") != -1:
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another mistake in your code, you don't need:

```
infile.read()
```

Because it reads all contens of infile and doesn't save it to any variable. And what is more important it moves you to the end of file, so there's no more lines to read.

In addition there's no need to manualy close file, it's better to use with statement:

```
with open("test.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        # do what you want
# here file will be close automaticaly, when we exit "with" scope.
```